# How to use Automapper when class structure is not fully same

Tags: c#, automapper

here is sample classes

```
public class Person {
    public int Id{ get; set ;}
    public string FirstName{ get; set ;}
    public string LastName{ get; set ;}
    public string Email{ get; set ;}
    public string PhoneNo{ get; set ;}
    public string Sex{ get; set ;}
}

public class PersonView {
    public int Id{ get; set ;}
    public string FirstName{ get; set ;}
    public string LastName{ get; set ;}
    public string Mail{ get; set ;}
    public string Phone{ get; set ;}
    public string PostCode{ get; set ;}
}
```

now please see my two class structure. there few fields are same and some time fields name are bit different but same 
as example Email & PhoneNo are there in PersonView but name is bit different. so in that case how to map ?

another scenario is Sex & PostCode do not exist in each other same way? so guide me how field by field mapping will be possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map where the field names are different use need to explicitly define the mapping. Fields which are not in the destination model will be ignored (Sex in this case). Where there is a field in the destination that does not exist in the source then you could use a default value (Postcode in this case):

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>()
      .ForMember(pv => pv.Mail, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Email))
      .ForMember(pv => pv.Phone, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.PhoneNo))
      .ForMember(pv => pv.PostCode, opt => opt.UseValue("Unknown postcode"));

  var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Person,PersonView>(me);
```

Comment: i have one question that if u omit this line .ForMember(pv => pv.PostCode, opt => opt.UseValue("Unknown postcode")); then error will be thrown ? some time people may not like to map few fields in two model...then any problem occur ? looking for answer.

Comment: var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Person,PersonView>(me); what is me here? how me comes?

Comment: can we use automapper for C# 2.0 version ?

Comment: The variable me is an instance of the Person class. AutoMapper needs .Net framework 3.0 or above.